# How do I debug Facebook JavaScript api errors on my site?

Tags: javascript, debugging, facebook

I am adding a link to my site which will allow users to share what happened on the page on their Facebook wall.

To do this, I am utilizing the Facebook Javascript API.  I have the following code in my head.

```
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Later in the body, I am calling the code to publish to the user's stream.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
        FB.init({
            appId: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
            status: true, 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true,
            level  : "debug"
        }); 
    }; 
    streamPublish = function(){
        var session = Session.get('eres_user_data');
        var argumentsURL = "";
        var confirmFacebookTitle = "";
        var confirmFacebookMessage = "";

        if (session.promoCode != null && session.promoCode != ""){
            argumentsURL = "https://www.totalrewards.com/hotel-reservations/?propcode="+session.propCode+"&promotioncode="+session.promoCode+"view=ratecal&social="+session.propCode+"_tw_eResShare";
            confirmFacebookTitle = "It's time to play at "+session.propName+"!";
            confirmFacebookMessage = "I just saved "+ confirmationMod_session.savings+" by using the "+confirmationMod_session.promoName+" online at "+confirmationMod_session.propName+"!";
        }
        else if (session.showHotDeals == "Y"){
            argumentsURL = "https://www.totalrewards.com/hotel-reservations/?propcode="+session.propCode+"view=ratecal&showhotdeals=y&social="+session.propCode+"_tw_eResShare";
            confirmFacebookTitle = "I booked a smoking hot deal at "+session.propName+"!";
            confirmFacebookMessage = "I just made a reservation at "+session.propName+" using the 'Hot Deals Calendar'. Guaranteed lowest rates, and so easy to book. Wish me luck!";
        }
        else if (session.packageCode != null && session.packageCode != ""){
            argumentsURL = "https://www.totalrewards.com/hotel-reservations/?propcode="+session.propCode+"&packagecode="+session.packagecode+"view=ratecal&social="+session.propCode+"_tw_eResShare";
            confirmFacebookTitle = "I booked a "+session.packageName+" package deal at "+session.propName+"!";
            confirmFacebookMessage = "I just made a reservation at "+session.propName+" online. Guaranteed lowest rates, and so easy to book. Wish me luck!";
        }
        else{
            argumentsURL = "https://www.totalrewards.com/hotel-reservations/?propcode="+session.propCode+"&view=ratecal&social="+session.propCode+"_tw_eResShare";
            confirmFacebookTitle = "It's time to play at "+session.propName+"!";
            confirmFacebookMessage = "I just made a reservation at "+session.propName+" online. Guaranteed lowest rates, and so easy to book. Wish me luck!";
        }
        FB.ui(
           {
             method: 'stream.publish',
             display:'dialog',
             message: 'test',
             attachment: {
               name: confirmFacebookTitle,
               caption: '',
               description: confirmFacebookMessage,
               'media': [{ 
                    'type': 'image',
                    'src': 'http://www.caesars.com/images/casinos/'+session.propCode+'MET_alt.png',
                    'href': argumentsURL
                    }],
               href: argumentsURL
             },
             action_links: [
               { text: 'Find Rates', href: argumentsURL}
             ],
             user_message_prompt: 'Tell your friends about your getaway.'
           },
           function(response) {
           }
         );

    }
```

When the user clicks the "share" link, a facebook window comes up, but there is only a text error.  "An error occurred. Please try again later." is all that is shown, along with the url of 
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/stream.publish?action_links=[{%22text%22:%22Find%20Rates%22,%22href%22:%22https://www.totalrewards.com/hotel-reservations/%3Fpropcode%3DMET%26view%3Dratecal%26social%3DMET_tw_eResShare%22}]&attachment={%22name%22:%22It's%20time%20to%20play%20at%20Harrah's%20Metropolis!%22,%22caption%22:%22%22,%22description%22:%22I%20just%20made%20a%20reservation%20at%20Harrah's%20Metropolis%20online.%20Guaranteed%20lowest%20rates,%20and%20so%20easy%20to%20book.%20Wish%20me%20luck!%22,%22media%22:[{%22type%22:%22image%22,%22src%22:%22http://www.caesars.com/images/casinos/METMET_alt.png%22,%22href%22:%22https://www.totalrewards.com/hotel-reservations/%3Fpropcode%3DMET%26view%3Dratecal%26social%3DMET_tw_eResShare%22}],%22href%22:%22https://www.totalrewards.com/hotel-reservations/%3Fpropcode%3DMET%26view%3Dratecal%26social%3DMET_tw_eResShare%22}&display=popup&locale=en_US&message=test&next=http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php%23cb%3Df2b8d16234%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df2f644938%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&sdk=joey&user_message_prompt=Tell%20your%20friends%20about%20your%20getaway`.

How in the world do I troubleshoot this issue?  I don't see any javascript errors, and I don't know where any errors would show up.  Any help would be appreciated to get my past this issue. "An Error Occured, please try again later" isn't really helping me at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this javascript lib is out of date :) Yes may be because this question just celebrate his first birthday. The stream.publish will disapear shortly.